# Check if variable exists - Terraform template syntax

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I'm trying to check if a variable exists on a template file using terraform template syntax, but I get error that `This object does not have an attribute named "proxy_set_header`.

```
$ cat nginx.conf.tmpl

%{ for location in jsondecode(locations) }
location ${location.path} {
    %{ if location.proxy_set_header }
       proxy_set_header ${location.proxy_set_header};
    %{ endif }
}
%{ endfor }
```

I tried with `if location.proxy_set_header != ""` and `if location.proxy_set_header` without success.

How to check if a variable exists with the String Templates?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Terraform 0.12.20 or later then you can use the new function [`can`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/can.html) to concisely write a check like this:

```
%{ for location in jsondecode(locations) }
location ${location.path} {
    %{ if can(location.proxy_set_header) }
       proxy_set_header ${location.proxy_set_header};
    %{ endif }
}
%{ endfor }
```

The `can` function returns true if the given expression could evaluate without an error.

---

The documentation does suggest preferring [`try`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html) in most cases, but in this particular situation your goal is to show nothing at all if that attribute isn't present, and so this equivalent approach with `try` is, I think, harder to understand for a future reader:

```
%{ for location in jsondecode(locations) }
location ${location.path} {
    ${ try("proxy_set_header ${location.proxy_set_header};", "") }
}
%{ endfor }
```

As well as being (subjectively) more opaque as to the intent, this ignores the recommendation in the `try` docs of using it only with attribute lookup and type conversion expressions. Therefore I think the `can` usage above is justified due to its relative clarity, but either way should work.

Comment: any idea why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75084298/no-function-named-try-when-rendering-template-in-terraform) doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like the following, using `contains` and `keys`

```
%{ for location in jsondecode(locations) }
location ${location.path} {
    %{ if contains(keys(location), "proxy_set_header") }
       proxy_set_header ${location.proxy_set_header};
    %{ endif }
}
%{ endfor }
```

The parsed JSON essentially becomes a `map` which can be checked for key contents.

I tested this with the following code

```
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = file("${path.module}/file.template")
  vars = {
    locations = <<DOC
[
  {
    "path": "foo",
    "proxy_set_header": "foohdr"
  },
  {
    "path": "bar"
  }
]
DOC
  }
}

output "answer" {
  value = data.template_file.init.rendered
}
```

and it had the following output

```
Outputs:

answer = 
location foo {

       proxy_set_header foohdr;

}

location bar {

}
```