# No function named try when rendering template in terraform

Tags: templates, terraform

I am rendering a `.json` document containing a policy:

```
data "template_file" "my_role_policy" {
  template = file("iam_role_policy_template.json")

  vars = {
    ACCESS_TO_SM   = false
    FOO            = bar
  }
}
```

Within the `iam_role_policy_template.json`, I have the following snippet

```json
        %{ if try(ACCESS_TO_SM, false) }
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
            ],
            "Resource": "s3://my-bucket/my-path"
        }
        %{ endif }
```

This is because there are other `.tf` files using the same template that (for some reason) may not pass this variable.

The plan fails with the error

> Error: failed to render : <template_file>:20,15-18: Call to unknown function; There is no function named "try".

I thought it was possible to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231262/2409793) it in a template.

Comment: Try switching to `templatefile` built-in function.

Comment: You mean instead of file?

Comment: No, instead of the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hashicorp/template` provider and its `template_file` data source have been obsolete since 2019 and so the set of available functions and language features in that provider is effectively frozen at whatever Terraform supported at that time. It's still available for installation only for backward-compatibility for those using very old Terraform modules.

The `try` function is considerably newer and so it isn't available in that provider and never will be. As recommended in [the `template_file` documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file), you should migrate to using the [`templatefile` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile), which is a built-in part of the Terraform language and so always matches the features of whatever version of Terraform you are using.

You can replace your `data "template_file"` block with a local value whose definition is a call to the `templatefile` function:

```
locals {
  role_policy = templatefile("${path.module}/iam_role_policy_template.json", {
    ACCESS_TO_SM   = false
    FOO            = "bar"
  })
}
```

Elsewhere in your module, each place where you refer to `data.template_file.my_role_policy.rendered` you can refer to `local.role_policy` instead.

Once you've made this change, Terraform should accept your use of `try` inside the template.

---

Separately: in your example the `try` function call is not achieving anything, because the top-level variables like `ACCESS_TO_SM` are *always* either defined or raise a static reference error. You can't use `try` with direct access to top-level template variables, on to attributes and elements of collections.

For example, if you pass a map into your template then you can use `try` to handle the case where an expected map key isn't present:

```
templatefile(..., {
  example_map = tomap({
    "a" = 1
  })
})
```

```
${ try(example.map["b"], 2) }
```

...but it is not effective to use `try` when its first argument is just a direct reference to a variable, because Terraform requires that you define all of the variables that the template uses and so the template would not be evaluated at all if you did not include `ACCESS_TO_SM` in the set of defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `try` with [%{} directtive](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#directives). You would have to use `try` before template:

```
data "template_file" "my_role_policy" {
  template = file("iam_role_policy_template.json")

  vars = {
    ACCESS_TO_SM   = try(SOME-EXPRESSION, false)
    FOO            = "bar"
  }
}
```

then the template would be:

```
%{ if ACCESS_TO_SM == "true" }
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
    ],
    "Resource": "s3://my-bucket/my-path"
}
%{ endif }
```